# multiple bracket multiple line problem

Tags: equations, align, multline

I am having problem with eq like

```
\begin{align*}
\left( \left ... \right.\\
\left.        \right)\right) 
\end{\align*}
```

This gives me error.
I know that the solution will for

```
\begin{align*}
\left(  ... \right.\\
\left.        \right)
\end{\align*}
```

Comment: What's your question? Is it about the first code block or the second?

Comment: `\begin{align*}
\left( \left( ... \right.\right.\\
\left.\left.        \right)\right) 
\end{\align*}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, in first equation, you opened two `\left` and closed with one `\right`, then second equation, you opened one `\left` and closed with two `\right` which was wrong, opening and closing should be with in equations and the correct `MWE` is:

```
\begin{align*}
\left( \left( ... \right.\right.\\
\left.\left.        \right)\right) 
\end{\align*}
```

PS: As you are not provided full `MWE`, me too following the same...

Comment: this has the same issue as the "solution" shown in the question that the ( and ) will typically  be of different sizes.